# Is it safe to keep a static reference to a SharedPreferences and its Editor?

Tags: android, android-context

Im going to make something like:

```
private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesInstance;
public static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(final Context context){
    if (context==null)
        return sharedPreferencesInstance;
    if (sharedPreferencesInstance == null)
        sharedPreferencesInstance = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferencesInstance;
}

private static SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPreferencesEditorInstance;
public static SharedPreferences.Editor getSharedPreferencesEditor(final Context context){
    if (context==null)
        return sharedPreferencesEditorInstance;
    if (sharedPreferencesEditorInstance == null)
        sharedPreferencesEditorInstance = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    return sharedPreferencesEditorInstance;
}
```

but is it safe in meaning of Context leaks?

Comment: if you will always have the context in your call why not using a static method that will always get the new instance?

Comment: Could call the method with null after a previuos call with real Context and a "singleton way".

Comment: This by far isn't the right way to a singleton class hold the shared preferences, if you want to get your shared preferences from a singletone class then the context should be stored in your class constructor. Also you can just do that extending your application class, then use your Application Context, like that: MyApp.this.getApplicationContext() to get your context

Comment: I wrote a couple of comments, then deleted them since my choice of words was poor.  Let me put it this way, passing an Activity to anything which is static should set off your code smell alarm.  Given that there is always a better way, just don't do it!  Here, application context is a good choice.

Comment: changed a code to use ApplicationContext.

Comment: Anything that depends on just `getApplicationContext` is safe to hold on forever since application context itself is an everlasting singleton. I'd also prefer the way you do it, i.e. require any `Context` as parameter and `.getApplicationContext()` it so you can be sure that the context is safe to keep. Shortcuts like `MyApp.getApplicationContext()` are IMO bad style. http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/ also uses nearly your singleton approach and that style is used in several places inside android as well.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To answer the question authoritatively, it is **safe** to store the `SharedPreferences` instance as a static reference. According to the javadocs it is a singleton, so its source from `getSharedPreferences` is already a static reference.

It is **not safe** to store the `SharedPreferences.Editor` because it is possible two threads may be manipulating the same editor object at the same time. Granted, the damage this would cause is relatively minor if you happen to have already been doing it. Instead, get an instance of an editor in each editing method.

I *highly recommend* using a static reference to your `Application` object instead of passing in `Context` objects for every get. All instances of your `Application` class are singletons per process anyways, and passing around `Context` objects is usually bad practice because it tends to lead to memory leaks via reference holding, and is unnecessarily verbose.

Finally, to answer the unasked question if you should lazily-load or greedily-initialize the reference to your static `SharedPreferences`, you should lazily load in a static getter method. It *may* work to greedily-initialize a reference with `final static SharedPreferences sReference = YourApplication.getInstance().getSharedPreferences()` depending on the chain of class imports, but it would be too easy for the class loader to initialize the reference before the `Application` has already called `onCreate` (where you would initialize the `YourApplication` reference), causing a null-pointer exception. In summary:

```
class YourApplication {
    private static YourApplication sInstance;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sInstance = this;
    }
    public static YourApplication get() {
        return sInstance;
    }
}

class YourPreferencesClass {
    private static YourPreferencesClass sInstance;
    private final SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    public static YourPreferencesClass get() {
        if (sInstance == null)
            sInstance = new YourPreferencesClass();
        return sInstance;
    }

    private final YourPreferencesClass() {
        mPrefs = YourApplication.get().getSharedPreferences("Prefs", 0);
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        mPrefs.edit().putInt("value", value).apply();
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return mPrefs.getInt("value", 0);
    }
}
```

You will then use your statically available preferences class as such:

```
YourPreferencesClass.get().setValue(1);
```

A final word about the thread-safety and memory observability. Some astute observers may notice that `YourPreferencesClass.get()` isn't synchronized, and hence dangerous because two threads may initialize two different objects. However, you can safely avoid synchronization. As I mentioned earlier, `getSharedPreferences` already returns a single static reference, so even in the extremely rare case of `sInstance` being set twice, the same underlying reference to `SharedPreferences` is used. Regarding the static instance of `YourApplication.sInstance`, it is also safe without synchronization or the `volatile` keyword. There are no user threads in your application running before `YourApplication.onCreate`, and therefore the happens-before relationship defined for newly created threads ensures that the static reference will be visible to all future threads that may access said reference.

Comment: I realize this is pretty old but mPrefs.getEditor() should be mPrefs.edit() no? I don't see getEditor on SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is safe. I always use a "KeyStoreController" with a static reference to a SharedPreferences object (singleton). I would suggest you to use an Application context instead of passing  a context every time. This is an example of my code:

```
public class KeyStoreController{


private static KeyStoreController singleton = null;
private SharedPreferences preferences = null;

private KeyStoreController(Context c){
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
}

public static KeyStoreController getKeyStore(){
    if( singleton == null){
        singleton = new KeyStoreController(MainApplication.getContext());
    }
    return singleton;
}

public void setPreference(String key, Object value) {
    // The SharedPreferences editor - must use commit() to submit changes
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    if(value instanceof Integer )
        editor.putInt(key, ((Integer) value).intValue());
    else if (value instanceof String)
        editor.putString(key, (String)value);
    else if (value instanceof Boolean)
        editor.putBoolean(key, (Boolean)value);
    else if (value instanceof Long)
        editor.putLong(key, (Long)value);
    editor.commit();
}

public int getInt(String key, int defaultValue) {
    return preferences.getInt(key, defaultValue);
}

public String getString(String key, String defaultValue) {
    return preferences.getString(key, defaultValue);
}

public boolean getBoolean(String key, boolean defaultValue) {
    return preferences.getBoolean(key, defaultValue);
}

public long getLong(String key, long defaultValue) {
    return preferences.getLong(key, defaultValue);
}
```

Comment: Actually (and just to be sure) you could always call context.getApplicationContext() while taking any context as a method's parameter (including true ApplicationContext)... Also using this way you dont have to have a static method like MainApplication.getContext().

Comment: yes, but calling the MainApplication.getContext() and having the application context always accessible is more convenient because you'll be able to access the sharedpreferences from anywhere in your application ;)

Comment: Keeping in mind that ApplicationContext kept as a static reference  means you should call some init method of KeyStoreController sending any Context at a time app starts just to instantiate SharedPrefs ref (or in App's onCreate()). Thats true if you don't need to access a Context any time further.

Comment: That's right @Stan
.. I have a static reference in my MainApplication class for easy access

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing around the `Context` it is best to be passing along an `ApplicationContext`.  It might be easier if you just make a static `ApplicationContext` to reference and then just use the `SharedPreferences` when you need them from within your classes (if that approach works for you).

If you have the argument for the calls a `Context` then you shouldn't have to worry about leaks unless you are holding on to it.

But, I think that you will be just fine doing what you are doing conceptually.

Comment: I mean I know that static ref to a View (ie TextView) is Context leaks unsafe. But Im not sure about SharedPreferences thats why Im asking this...

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a static class and use it as a utility so you never have to keep a reference to your `SharedPreferences` at all. You also never have to initialize an instance of this class and can just call PreferencesUtil.getUserName(context) so long as you have a context to supply.

```
public static class PreferencesUtil{

    private static final String USER_NAME_KEY = "uname";

    public static void setUserName(String name, Context c){
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(c);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString(USER_NAME_KEY, name);
        editor.commit();
    }


    public static String getUserName(Context c){
        return getPreferences(c).getString(USER_NAME_KEY, "");
    }

    private SharedPreferences getPreferences(Context context){
        return context.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

}
```